# How to write text in console after appending?

Tags: c#, .net

After appending a text file I want the console to write the new complete text of the txt file. However, the line I've just added is not written in the console. What am I doing wrong?

You can see my code below.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileExercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Text.txt";    

            //Read all lines    
            string lines = File.ReadAllText(path);

            Console.WriteLine(lines);   

            //Add line to original document
            File.AppendAllLines(@path, new string[] { "" + "This line is added 
            by Visual Studio" });   

            //Read new lines
            Console.WriteLine(lines);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, I expect to read the text already present in the file and the line "This line is added by Visual Studio". But all I'm getting is the old text.

Comment: You append the text to the file but print the variable lines. YIu need to reread the lines or you have to  append first

Comment: You read the content file into a variable (in memory), then _later_ you modify the file. But the content of the variable is still the content you have read from the file _before_ modifying it. Think of it this way: You make a photo copy of a page. Then you alter the page. Will the existing photo copy also be altered? No, of course not. You would have to make a new photo copy, in other words: read the file (into the variable) again.

Comment: In case you're wondering - I didn't edit the code in the question because it didn't belong there. Rather, because it wasn't directly related to the question. It just makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `lines` variable again after appending your text, like you originally did.

```
lines = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Which results in the following for you:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileExercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Text.txt";    

            //Read all lines
            string lines = File.ReadAllText(path);

            Console.WriteLine(lines);

            //Add line to original document
            File.AppendAllLines(@path, new string[] { "" + "This line is added 
            by Visual Studio" });    

            lines = File.ReadAllText(path);

            //Read new lines
            Console.WriteLine(lines);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @elgonzo - The `Sleep` was in the OP. I edited it out, then a second ago I edited from this answer. This answer contained it from the OP's code.

Comment: No I'm still learning and adding the sleeps allows me to observe everything that's happening. I just put them in there for educational purposes :P

Comment: @elgonzo I literally copied OP's example. What Isabelle's purpose of sleeping is, doesn't matter to me. I answered her question. Downvoting shouldn't happen for this reason. I answered the matter.

Comment: Already deleted my comment after noticing Scott editing the answer to make it fit the edited question ;-) So, all is good...

Answer (score 1):

When you're appending to the file with `File.AppendAllLines` the file is updated with the additional text but the values in `lines` doesn't change, it still has the text that was in the file before appending.

There's a few ways to do what you want, here's one example:

```
//Read all the text in the file
string lines = File.ReadAllText(path);

//Output the original text
Console.Write(lines);

//Add your new line
lines += "This line is added by Visual Studio" + Environment.NewLine;

//Write the now updated text to the file
File.WriteAllText(path, lines);

//Output the new text
Console.Write(lines);
```

If you're planning to append many lines you may want to look into streaming the file and appending lines that way or even using the `StringBuilder`.

**Edit**

I should have mentioned why I don't just call `File.ReadAllText` again. This strategy would work but it's very inefficient as it would require that the entire contents of the file be read again. Depending on the size of the file this could take a significant amount of time. It's cleaner and more efficient to modify the data in memory like in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Afther appending the text to the file you need to read the file again.
The 'Lines' variable still hold the text from the last time it reads the file.

```
string lines;
lines = File.ReadAllText(path);
Console.WriteLine(lines);

//Add line to original document
File.AppendAllLines(@path, new string[] { "" + "This line is added 
by Visual Studio" });

//Read new lines
lines = File.ReadAllText(path);

Console.WriteLine(lines);
```